Deadlock on SQL Server only when running database locally
When trying to test locally an application (Java, Spring boot, hibernate, SQl server as database) i notice a significant amount of deadlock, the application and the database are running on my computer during the test. No deadlock happens on staging or production environment (however my computer is far more powerfull than the servers and the database run in a container on my computer).
I'm testing a specific part of the application which does a batch import, basically it consumme rows from a table which represent events on Contract and Items (a contract have multiple items) and import them in two tables, "contract" and "item", storing them in their final state.
The events are consumed by multiple thread, but a thread only handle the events pertaining to a single contract, thus the different threads don't interract with the same rows in the contract and item table :
There seems to be a specific portion of code (dedicated to a type of contract) that triggers deadlock, i have collected a deadlock report from sql server, and the application trace with transaction log and hibernate logging, but i'm not familiar with deadlock and i'm having a hard time figuring out how i can find out what is really happening.
The relevant tables DDL :
use INVOICE
go

create table dbo.contract
(
    reference             varchar(16)   not null
        primary key,
    client_code           varchar(64)   not null,
    created_date          date          not null,
    agency_reference      varchar(32),
    channel               varchar(32),
    external_code         varchar(64),
    new_client            bit default 1 not null,
    owner_type            varchar(32),
    status                varchar(32),
    target_period         varchar(7),
    type                  varchar(32),
    created_by_isilis     bit default 1 not null,
    partial_mobility      bit default 0 not null,
    new_iban              varchar(36),
    new_bank_account_name varchar(70),
    old_iban              varchar(70),
    emitter_iban          varchar(70),
    owner_name            varchar(110),
    signed_date           date,
    already_invoiced      bit default 0 not null,
    is_dsp2               bit default 0 not null,
    dsp2_status           varchar(36)
)
go

create index idx_contract_period_client
    on dbo.contract (target_period, client_code)
go

create index idx_contract_period_client_type
    on dbo.contract (target_period, client_code, type)
go

use INVOICE
go

create table dbo.item
(
    reference           varchar(16)   not null
        primary key,
    contract_reference  varchar(16)   not null,
    name                varchar(256),
    created_date        date          not null,
    sent_date           date,
    status              varchar(32),
    target_period       varchar(7),
    finalised_by_isilis bit default 0 not null,
    physical            bit default 0 not null,
    small               bit default 0 not null,
    has_email           bit default 0 not null,
    ics                 varchar(64),
    is_dsp2             bit default 0 not null
)
go

create index ITEM_CONTRACT_REFERENCE
    on dbo.item (contract_reference, reference)
go

The sql server deadlock report :
<event name="xml_deadlock_report" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2024-10-10T12:59:49.190Z">
<data name="xml_report">
    <value>
        <deadlock>
            <victim-list>
                <victimProcess id="processe00058ca8"/>
            </victim-list>
            <process-list>
                <process id="processe00058ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 11:1:14032 "
                         waittime="4961" ownerId="7994918" transactionname="implicit_transaction"
                         lasttranstarted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.220" XDES="0xe00584470" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1"
                         kpid="832" status="suspended" spid="78" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1"
                         lastbatchstarted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.227" lastbatchcompleted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.227"
                         lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.227" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"
                         hostname="benoit-XPS" hostpid="422222" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                         xactid="7994918" currentdb="11" currentdbname="INVOICE" lockTimeout="4294967295"
                         clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
                    <executionStack>
                        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="3400"
                               sqlhandle="0x0200000017f60a2aa415215a18d28099390faa3cb6ef87490000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                            unknown
                        </frame>
                        <frame procname="unknown" line="1"
                               sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                            unknown
                        </frame>
                    </executionStack>
                    <inputbuf>
                        (@P0 nvarchar(4000))select contracten0_.reference as referenc1_1_1_,
                        contracten0_.agency_reference as agency_r2_1_1_, contracten0_.already_invoiced as
                        already_3_1_1_, contracten0_.channel as channel4_1_1_, contracten0_.client_code as
                        client_c5_1_1_, contracten0_.created_by_isilis as created_6_1_1_, contracten0_.created_date
                        as created_7_1_1_, contracten0_.dsp2_status as dsp8_1_1_, contracten0_.emitter_iban as
                        emitter_9_1_1_, contracten0_.external_code as externa10_1_1_, contracten0_.is_dsp2 as
                        is_dsp11_1_1_, contracten0_.new_bank_account_name as new_ban12_1_1_, contracten0_.new_client
                        as new_cli13_1_1_, contracten0_.new_iban as new_iba14_1_1_, contracten0_.old_iban as
                        old_iba15_1_1_, contracten0_.owner_name as owner_n16_1_1_, contracten0_.owner_type as
                        owner_t17_1_1_, contracten0_.partial_mobility as partial18_1_1_, contracten0_.signed_date as
                        signed_19_1_1_, contracten0_.status as status20_1_1_, contracten0_.target_period as
                        target_21_1_1_, contracten0_.type as type22_1_1_, items1_.contract_reference as con
                    </inputbuf>
                </process>
                <process id="processe007048c8" taskpriority="0" logused="360" waitresource="PAGE: 11:1:14032 "
                         waittime="4954" ownerId="7994848" transactionname="implicit_transaction"
                         lasttranstarted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.203" XDES="0xe41498470" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="13"
                         kpid="1904" status="suspended" spid="73" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2"
                         lastbatchstarted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.220" lastbatchcompleted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.220"
                         lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.220" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"
                         hostname="benoit-XPS" hostpid="422222" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)"
                         xactid="7994848" currentdb="11" currentdbname="INVOICE" lockTimeout="4294967295"
                         clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
                    <executionStack>
                        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="712" stmtend="1624"
                               sqlhandle="0x0200000091dc371910eb29b468f5be145b6ba451aec4ee520000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                            unknown
                        </frame>
                        <frame procname="unknown" line="1"
                               sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                            unknown
                        </frame>
                    </executionStack>
                    <inputbuf>
                        (@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 bit,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 bit,@P5 date,@P6
                        nvarchar(4000),@P7 nvarchar(4000),@P8 nvarchar(4000),@P9 bit,@P10 nvarchar(4000),@P11
                        bit,@P12 nvarchar(4000),@P13 nvarchar(4000),@P14 nvarchar(4000),@P15 nvarchar(4000),@P16
                        bit,@P17 date,@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 nvarchar(4000),@P20 nvarchar(4000),@P21
                        nvarchar(4000))update contract set agency_reference= @P0 , already_invoiced= @P1 , channel=
                        @P2 , client_code= @P3 , created_by_isilis= @P4 , created_date= @P5 , dsp2_status= @P6 ,
                        emitter_iban= @P7 , external_code= @P8 , is_dsp2= @P9 , new_bank_account_name= @P10 ,
                        new_client= @P11 , new_iban= @P12 , old_iban= @P13 , owner_name= @P14 , owner_type= @P15 ,
                        partial_mobility= @P16 , signed_date= @P17 , status= @P18 , target_period= @P19 , type= @P20
                        where reference= @P21
                    </inputbuf>
                </process>
                <process id="processe2c099088" taskpriority="0" logused="896"
                         waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594044284928 (082f6ca0eea6)" waittime="4950" ownerId="7994913"
                         transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.220"
                         XDES="0xe48904470" lockMode="U" schedulerid="10" kpid="960" status="suspended" spid="84"
                         sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.223"
                         lastbatchcompleted="2024-10-10T12:59:44.223" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.223"
                         clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="benoit-XPS" hostpid="422222"
                         loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7994913" currentdb="11"
                         currentdbname="INVOICE" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672"
                         clientoption2="128058">
                    <executionStack>
                        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="712" stmtend="1624"
                               sqlhandle="0x0200000091dc371910eb29b468f5be145b6ba451aec4ee520000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                            unknown
                        </frame>
                        <frame procname="unknown" line="1"
                               sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                            unknown
                        </frame>
                    </executionStack>
                    <inputbuf>
                        (@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 bit,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 bit,@P5 date,@P6
                        nvarchar(4000),@P7 nvarchar(4000),@P8 nvarchar(4000),@P9 bit,@P10 nvarchar(4000),@P11
                        bit,@P12 nvarchar(4000),@P13 nvarchar(4000),@P14 nvarchar(4000),@P15 nvarchar(4000),@P16
                        bit,@P17 date,@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 nvarchar(4000),@P20 nvarchar(4000),@P21
                        nvarchar(4000))update contract set agency_reference= @P0 , already_invoiced= @P1 , channel=
                        @P2 , client_code= @P3 , created_by_isilis= @P4 , created_date= @P5 , dsp2_status= @P6 ,
                        emitter_iban= @P7 , external_code= @P8 , is_dsp2= @P9 , new_bank_account_name= @P10 ,
                        new_client= @P11 , new_iban= @P12 , old_iban= @P13 , owner_name= @P14 , owner_type= @P15 ,
                        partial_mobility= @P16 , signed_date= @P17 , status= @P18 , target_period= @P19 , type= @P20
                        where reference= @P21
                    </inputbuf>
                </process>
            </process-list>
            <resource-list>
                <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="14032" dbid="11" subresource="FULL" objectname="INVOICE.dbo.contract"
                          id="locke5cd4b880" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594045267968">
                    <owner-list>
                        <owner id="processe2c099088" mode="IX"/>
                    </owner-list>
                    <waiter-list>
                        <waiter id="processe00058ca8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                    </waiter-list>
                </pagelock>
                <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="14032" dbid="11" subresource="FULL" objectname="INVOICE.dbo.contract"
                          id="locke5cd4b880" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594045267968">
                    <owner-list>
                        <owner id="processe00058ca8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
                    </owner-list>
                    <waiter-list>
                        <waiter id="processe007048c8" mode="IX" requestType="wait"/>
                    </waiter-list>
                </pagelock>
                <keylock hobtid="72057594044284928" dbid="11" objectname="INVOICE.dbo.contract"
                         indexname="PK__contract__FD90DA98DD2927B2" id="locke52d3bd00" mode="X"
                         associatedObjectId="72057594044284928">
                    <owner-list>
                        <owner id="processe007048c8" mode="X"/>
                    </owner-list>
                    <waiter-list>
                        <waiter id="processe2c099088" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
                    </waiter-list>
                </keylock>
            </resource-list>
        </deadlock>
    </value>
</data>

The execution plan of a queries that appear in the deadlock report : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkazSLS1kg and https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJOZvIHJJg
I have uploaded the application logs with transaction and sql here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K4Lt4XwdSr7fgRJi98N82HT8u61X2DJZ/view?usp=drive_link
I'm looking for advice on what i can improve in the application to reduce the amount of deadlock.

To diagnose a deadlock, we need at a minimum: the actual raw SQL queries involved, the relevant tables and index definitions, the query plan (please share via https://brentoazr.com/pastetheplan) and the deadlock XDL/XML graph (you need to get the deadlock report as XML not as text). Without this info it's impossible to answer.

I have edited the post to include the informations you mentioned. There are queries included in the deadlock report, is it enough or do you need all the query the application makes during the import ?

What does the application do? The XML graph contains inputbuf that contain the queries. This shows that one connection is trying to select from the contract table while 2 others are trying to update it. Queries don't "consume" data, so what does that mean? Are you trying to use multiple Hibernate sessions to perform an ETL job on lots of data? Are you using explicit transactions in code that would keep the Shared (ie read) locks beyond just the read operation?

No, the deadlock graph only contains the queries partially cut off. Fortunately the query plans contain the actual queries. But from what I can see from the graph, I suspect there may be multiple statements executed in a single transaction. If so please give all those statements with query plans.

Looks like there is an issue with the select query, wheer Hibernate is passing a 1 integer instead of '1' string for the reference parameter. So it's causing the column to be implicitly converted, and therefore a huge unnecessary table scan.

@PanagiotisKanavos The application is indeed performing ETL on lots of data, there are multiple thread (100 in production) that reads "events" (ie a contract is created or updated) from a source table and insert/update data in the contract and item tables to reflect the most up to date state of the contract and items. Each of those threads is limited to a single contract (and it's items), so two thread should not interract on the same rows.
By "a transaction that keep the shared (read) lock" do you mean a transaction that stays open after executing a select statement ?

@Benoit that's the problem then - ORMs are completely inadequate for ETL. They just aren't used and can't be made to work for anything that small data. The ORM programming model is the exact opposite of the ETL model. Instead of extracting, transforming and loading streams of data, an ORM's job is to load a graph of related entities and persist it. At best you can call that ELT but it's nowhere close to loading a Dataframe in memory, processing it and saving it. ETL jobs store data to staging tables too, only upserting the target table when done

I suspect you tried to improve the unavoidable bad performance by creating multiple sessions in parallel, some of which are loading data from the target while others are persisting the changes to the same target table. That alone is enough to increase blocking. If the target table lacks proper indexes the read/write operations may end up locking more rows than needed. The deadlock graph shows 3 conflicting connections, which suggests each one is locking rows needed by the other. The real solution is to either stop using the ORM for ETL, or stop using concurrent operations

@Charlieface Hibernate does not show the arguments, to get the plan i add to fill the missing argument and i just put a 1 there without realising it wasn't the right type. Here's the plan updated with the correct type : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1UTvrIk1l sorry for the confusion.
I will check if there are multiple queries in a single transaction and give you the plan

@Benoit providing extra information wont help fix the real problem - wrong technique and tooling. Posting the Java source that tries to use multiple concurrent sessions could help but only a little. One way you can fix the problem is to write to a staging table instead of the target table. Once importing is finished, then update the target table. That import will always be slower than using JDBC and SQLServerBulkCopy though

I'm very doubtful that these statements by themselves could cause a deadlock (assuming you did fix what I said). because they are both clustered index seeks. The fact one of the three processes is a select but is holding an IX lock is also indicative, as is the fact one of the update processes is requesting a second page lock after already holding a key lock, that really what's going on here is that you have multiple statements in a single transaction, but you aren't showing us that.

As pointed out in the comment there are multiple issues with this application :

it's using an ORM for ETL
the entities used by Spring data are misconfigured, this trigger a select query with every insert or update

Fixing the first item is not possible because this would mean a complete rewrite of the application.
I fixed the second item by implementing the Persistable interface on the entities, this lightly improved the situation but deadlock were still happening with a relatively low parallelism (10 threads).
What completely fixed the problem was removing those two indexes :
create index idx_contract_period_client
    on dbo.contract (target_period, client_code)
go

create index idx_contract_period_client_type
    on dbo.contract (target_period, client_code, type)
go

Thoses indexes are indexing field with very low cardinality, target_period has the same value for almost all rows and while client_code has more values it still has a very low cardinality (ie: 30 000 rows have the same value).
Without those indexes i can set the parallelism to a hundred thread and not a single deadlock happens.
However i still don't understand why there is no problem running the same application, the same database schema and the same data in staging or production environment vs on my laptop. The only difference is the network latency and the fact that those environments have a full fledged SQL server vs just a container of the developer edition on my laptop.
